# bold text (uiwebview) not showing in iphone4

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, iphone-4, bold

I have html file in resources folder to load in uiwebview.
I need to get bold text styling.

iphone4 is not showing bold text at all. it's working fine in iphone 3Gs and ipod.
I tried...

```
<p><strong>bold</strong><br/><br/> <b>bold</b> </p>
```

both r not woking in iphone4.
Did anyone encounter this problem?
Thanks for any help...

Comment: Are you looking on the Simulator or the device itself?  Also, is there any CSS that is affecting these p or strong tags that we should know about?

Comment: i am testing on device. (iphone3Gs,iphone4 & ipod) only iphone4 got this problem. i don't set any font styling besides font-size in CSS.

Comment: Also what SDK version are you running?  What version of the OS is on your phones/devices?

Comment: SDK version - 4.1
iphone4 - iOS 4.0.1
iphone3Gs - iOS 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like jailbreak is the problem.
I restore my iphone4 and can see the text styling now.